# Install Qt addin for Visual Studio from Qt SDK package manager

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-addins

I can't find where to install the Qt addin for Visual Studio from the package manager that comes with Qt SDK.

Does the addin come with the module "Desktop Qt 4.8.1 - MSVC 2010"?

[image]

Comment: I dont know what SDK you are speaking about, but the VS addin is to be found here: http://releases.qt-project.org/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe . Since a lot people struggle with his: you know how to (n)make QT before you can use it via visual studio?

Comment: It's a separate executable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Visual Studio addin can be found on the [Qt Project's download page](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2), in the "Other" category. Download and run this installer, and follow the instructions in the wizard.

Answer (score 9):

The website has been updated, to download it go to [Qt open source download page](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-7) and click "Other Downloads" or "View all Downloads and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: How do I know which version of the Qt addin to install with different versions of Visual Studio?  I'm using Visual Studio 2012.